# Powershell referenced parameters

Tags: powershell

I am making a powershell script to configure user profile properties in SharePoint. However the "$bChanged" property is not being referenced back to the calling function. I thought parameters was always passed by reference?

```
function UpdateProperty($listproperty, $upproperty) {
    Write-Host "Lets call the function" + $upproperty.Name;
    $bChanged=$false;
    UpdatePropertyProperty $upproperty.DisplayName $listproperty.DisplayName $bChanged;
    #UpdatePropertyProperty $upproperty.disaplyOrder $listproperty.disaplyOrder $bChanged;
    #...

    if ($bChanged) {
        $upproperty.Commit();
        Write-Host "Property updated: " $upproperties.Name;
    }
}

function UpdatePropertyProperty($listpropprop, $uppropprop, $bChanged){
    if ($uppropprop -ne $listpropprop) {
        $bChanged=$true;
        $uppropprop = $listpropprop;
    }
}
```

Comment: `[bool]` is a value type, which is not passed by reference. See the linked question.

Comment: Great help. Since it is a duplicate, should I delete the question again, or what is best practice?

Comment: [You should leave it alone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). It could help someone else looking wording more similar to yours find the linked question.